# Which Kafka producer property to use when I no longer want to receive data after certain threshold?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Which Kafka producer property to use to achieve the following? 
 
I am using [UDP Kafka Bridge](https://github.com/agaoglu/udp-kafka-bridge) which sends the message from UDP port to Kafka topic. If the memory on the Kafka producer exceeds certain MB (Say 300 MB) drop all messages (With no retry) and again resume receiving messages when the producer memory goes down. 
Basically, I am trying to save my server from crashing if Kafka broker is not able to take any messages.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I am trying to save my server from crashing if Kafka is not able to take any messages.

As long as you don't call get on the Future returned from the send() call to the producer, you are fine. The Producer API works in the async mode.

Comment: block.on.buffer.full has been deprecated